# npm error when adding the latest work to the gh-pages deploy

Tags: reactjs, npm

I had to create a docs in order to see my react page displaying on github pages. I used h-pages deploy and keep getting this error when I am attempting to update the gh-pages.

The only branch I can access is *master.

I was doing :

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

this is the error :

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rReduxTable@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the rReduxTable@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marianaperez/.npm/_logs/2018-03-12T19_02_15_196Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you share the additional logging output and/or the contents of the .log file?

Comment: Can you share your `pacakge.json`

Answer (score 0):

this is my json package

```
    {
  "name": "rReduxTable",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "lint-staged": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "next",
    "react-sortable-table": "^1.3.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sanitize.css": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "homepage": "https://marianapt.github.io/reduxTable/",
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```